# Text align in one line

Tags: css, web, web-testing

I am a beginner that learning CSS and JS. I faced a problem in CSS. Please help... thanks

[My page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxt2p.png)

This is the page that I get the problem, and how can I align the text in one line and put them in average space. Check below what I imagine...

This is what I want
[Imagine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5kA1.png)

This is CSS code

```
body {
    background: #292929;
    }

h1 {
    font-family: Roboto;
    background-color: #292929;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #ffff
    }

div {
    align-content: center;
    }

.yesButton {
    margin-left: 350;
    left: 100;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 65;
    margin: initial;
    background-color: #575757;
    color: #ffff;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
.yesButton p {
    float: left;
    color: #ffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    }
    
.yesButton p:hover {
    background: #3d3d3d;
    color: #ffff;
    }
    
.noButton {
    margin-left: 500;
    left: 100;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #575757;
    color: #ffff;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
.noButton p {
    float: left;
    color: #ffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    }
    
.noButton p:hover {
    background: #3d3d3d;
    color: #ffff;
    }
    
div p{
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Thanks a lot...

Comment: please add HTML also so that we can see the class are cascading from where to where

Comment: add HTML code please!!

Comment: Some one can only help you if you share your whole code i.e `HTML` and `CSS` both. Please share your complete code in `code snippet`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should share your complete code.I assumed that you are using two `<p>` tags which you want to display in one line.
There are multiple solutions to do this and to make this better. But I am using your approach i.e `<p>` tag and made some minor changes to make the things happen.
Following is the `code snippet` for the `<p>` tag implementation. I updated your `CSS` which you can compare.
Also enhance your skills of `HTML` and `CSS`.

Checkout this;

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #292929;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: Roboto;
            background-color: #292929;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            color: #ffff
        }

        div {
            align-content: center !important;
        }

        .yesButton {
            margin-left: 350;
            left: 100;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 65;
            margin: initial;
            background-color: #575757;
            color: #ffff;
            text-align: right;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .yesButton p {
                float: left;
                color: #ffff;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 12px;
            }

                .yesButton p:hover {
                    background: #3d3d3d;
                    color: #ffff;
                }

        .noButton {
            margin-left: 500;
            left: 100;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #575757;
            color: #ffff;
            text-align: left;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .noButton p {
                float: left;
                color: #ffff;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 12px;
            }

                .noButton p:hover {
                    background: #3d3d3d;
                    color: #ffff;
                }

            div p {
                /*clear: both;
                display: inline-block;
                overflow: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;*/
                text-align:center;
            }

        div {
            width: 50%;
            float:left;
            color:#fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><p>No .....</p></div>
    <div><p>Yes .....</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without his HTML, your answer is only a wild guess and not a fact-based solution. [answer] Vote to close it instead.

Comment: Of course you are right @Rob, I asked him to share `HTML` and gave him an idea in my answer.